# CakePhp speed optimization

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My app is working very slow. I am using Cakephp 2.3.1 version. Will it be beneficial to load Model, Components and Helpers in the functions where they are needed? Right now I am calling them in class. eg:

```
class PanelsController extends AppController {
public $name = 'Panel';
public $uses = array(list of models goes here);
public $components = array(list of components goes here);
    .................
}
```

What other techniques do you suggest. Thanks

Comment: Load Models ONLY where needed, Lazy loading = Yucks!
Also, check for SQL Queries. Ideally, they will be the bottlenecks.

Comment: @KarmicDice Actually everything worked well on localhost, problem came as I shifted app to Godaddy server :(

Comment: You shouldn't be using `$uses` that often or not at all if your models are setup correctly. Cake will load the models you need by default. If your models and associations are large start using the containable behavior to get what you need. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Maybe you can mark it as staging server and check via debug 2 ?

Comment: also check that your database is not being called remotely. Godaddy is notoriously slow with remote mysql database connections.

Comment: @LetterSticker I managed to load majority of models where needed, containable behaviours have already been used... but the speed is still slow

Comment: @LetterSticker How to check for database?? I just created a new Godaddy database and used that credentials in cakephp > database

Comment: is it set as `localhost` in your `app/config/database.php` file or is it an ip or web address?

Comment: @LetterSticker it is set to godaddy db host url

Comment: that might be a problem if it's not set to localhost. It will be painfully slow... is there no way to set it to localhost with your godaddy setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`public $uses()` does not matter. you can add as many as you want. Cake will only lazyload them if needed somewhere.
Just make sure you got `recursive = -1` per default in your AppModel and only raise it or contain data you really need.

But your components will all be loaded and initialized right away.
You might want to reduce those.

Those two attributes cannot be your bottleneck, though. You must have some other serious issues.

Also don't make assumptions in debug mode. The real speed is measured/obseved with debug 0 where no additional debug info is gathered and the cache is not constantly replaced.

EDIT: Please note that my words above are only meant from a "speed point of view". It does not matter for speed. But it is not recommended to add models in $uses if you are able to reach those via relations and the relation chain.

So let's say you want to make a dashbard. In most cases you only need to add "User" model, since Profile, Images, and other models are usually directly accessable via `$this->User->Profile->foo($bar)` etc.

Comment: Suppose I have around 10 Models defined in `$uses` and I need only `Manager` Model for the following Query eg: `$this -> Manager -> find('all')`, will Cake only load `Manager` Model from `$uses` or all models will be loaded...?

Comment: with recursive = -1 and contained models only the Manager model of course (in 2.x)

Comment: @user1871640 You might have to rethink of your architecture. Are you saying that you are using 10 different models with a same controller ?

Comment: Mark, I'm surprised you encourage people to stuff lots of models into $uses but not to mention the better way to do it. The proper way to use models would be through associations. I've seen many silly things, including apps using no assocs at all but $uses and loadModel() all over the place...

Comment: I am not encouraging anything. I simply state the facts: it DOES NOT MATTER from a speed point of view. That was the question. And if you are not able to see that I am sry for you. Also no reason to downvote. I will add a statement, though, to clarify this.

Answer (score 8):

Here is something I would check if the site is performing slow

**Speed Optimization**

1. Enable [caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html)
2. Compress JS and CSS. ([A nice plugin that does this](http://github.com/mcurry/asset))
3. [A good speed optimization checklist](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

**Cake Practices**

1. Cake conventions are your best guidelines, the framework has been designed to be scaled with its conventions.
2. [Recursion](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive) and [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html), By default Cake fetches all related data when a query is fired. Both recursive level and containable behavior can limit the amount of data retrieved. If cake fetches all related data by default doesn't mean that you have to keep it that way.
3. **Keep your DB normalized**. This will allow you to defer many processes. For eg. when retrieving posts, cake automatically fetches all of its related data (Tags, comments). But when you have higher-order normalized DB, u can defer loading comments from an XHR/AJAX request. This will also allow you to serve comment related logic from comment's Model, Controller and View. Even if you bring related model data set limits for them.
4. You can also drop needs of counter query for related data by using Counter cache. [More Details here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)
5. [Cache your view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/cache.html)
6. You can cache query results manually too,

   ```
   Cache::write($this->Post->find("all"));
   ```

Try them out and you should be able experience amazing speed improvements.

Lastly, I do believe that Architecture of an application plays a big role in performance. Some times, we have to separate certain logic from a request Life cycle to boost the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use caching technique in cakephp to reduce time , for documentation see here :http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html

Do not use load Model, with large data code it will create problem.

Here is an article for your reference:(Tips to speed up cakephp app)
http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/13/what-really-speeds-up-your-cakephp-app/

Answer (score 0):

cakephp app slowness can be caused by a lot of reasons, have experienced so far:

- mysql server that was trying to do a dns lookup
- rendering a page with lot of links assembled via reverse routing
- memory issues

best way to find out seems to install `XDEBUG`[1](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)
and examine the profiling information